# Expressing power set of rationals

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to solve an exercise problem where $\{A\cap \mathbb{Q}:A
\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}=\mathbb{P}({\mathbb{Q})}$. The left hand side is a collection of rational numbers, so is contained in $\mathbb{P}({\mathbb{Q})}$. However showing the other side is tricky for me. Let $q\in \mathbb{P}({\mathbb{Q})}$, so $q=\{q_1,q_2,\ldots\}$. I need to show it is possible to find a $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A\cap \mathbb{Q}=q$. I thought I could find the smallest interval $(a,b)$ such that $q_i\in (a,b)$, for all $i$. I am stuck here and I do not have a formal way to establishing this. Could someone help me out?

Comment: What is $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the *borel sets* on $\mathbb{R}$, then every $Q \subset \mathbb{Q}$ is a countable union of singleton sets, and therefore $Q \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

In other words, since you always have $$
  Q = \bigcup_{q_n \in Q} \{q_n\} \quad\text{where $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Q}}$ is some enumeration of the rationals,}
$$
since all set sets $\{q_n\}$ are closed, and since closed sets are in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $Q$ as a countable union of borel sets is a borel set itself.

So just set $A = Q$ to see that if $Q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ then $Q$ is also an element of the set on the left-hand side.